# counting number of days in a date range using php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, function

I want to use a function to output the number of days within a date range

to do that i use something like below;

```
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to  = $_POST['to'];

$numdays = date_diff($to,$from);
```

but, when i out put the `$numdays` it always "0". How can I get this right ?

any clues ?

Comment: Please post example values. We couldn't possibly know what are you sending from the front end and which values `$from` and `$to` have.

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the string to a date format to calculate then convert back to a string to display it

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['from']) && isset($_POST['to'])){
    $from = date_create($_POST['from']);
    $to  = date_create($_POST['to']);
    $numdays = date_diff($from,$to);
    echo $numdays->format("%r%a days");

}
```

?>

```
<form action="" method="post">
<lable for="from">from</lable>
<input type="date" name="from" id="from">
<lable for="to">to</lable>
<input type="date" name="to" id="to">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: This also works, the issue I had was I have not created the Date Object.... Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

First create date object for dates using [date_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) and then calculate difference as:

```
$numdays = date_diff(date_create($_POST['from']), date_create($_POST['to']))->format('%a');
```

Read more about [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php).

Comment: But, What If I want to take the same day as count. like 07/07/18 to 07/07/18 should read as one day. will that possible. ?

Comment: Change its format as `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['from']))` and then use it in the above code.

Comment: didnt work. I used as follows  **$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['from']));** and when it comes to results section as follows  **$numdays = date_diff(date_create($to),date_create($from))->format('%a');**

Comment: What about `$to`? Had you also changed its format to `Y-m-d H:i:s` like `$from`?

Comment: Yes, i did. So i used something as follows,`$numdays = date_diff(date_create($to),date_create($from))->format('%a');+1` which may be not the best way, but it works to an extend.